# Cmd character font size

Tags: cmd

Did anybody know how to modify the character size in `cmd`. I already searched on internet but all what I found was the method from Proprieties. I need something like mode x,y but for characters.

Comment: With reference to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt

Comment: Its simple open cmd->press `alt+space+p`->in the properties tab change the font, thats how its meant to be done, what do you mean exactly by `I need something like mode x,y but for characters` ?

Comment: I mean for text size.

Comment: Go to the 2nd tab (Font tab),over there you can choose for sizes of character in terms `width x height`

Comment: Yes , I now but I need to do this from comand line. But thanks anyway.

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27127760/1683264) for a way to change the font size programmatically invoking a PowerShell command within a cmd session.

Answer (score 3):

You can not change (or at least i don't know how to do it) the properties of the current console from command line without some third party tool.

BUT, you can customize the creation of a new console

```
@echo off

    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion

    set "consoleName=testing"

    :: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978570.aspx
    (   reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f 
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "FaceName"         /t "REG_SZ"     /d "Consolas"
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "FontFamily"       /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00000036
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "FontSize"         /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00080004
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "FontWeight"       /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00000000
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "QuickEdit"        /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00000000
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "ScreenBufferSize" /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00200040
        reg add "HKCU\Console\%consoleName%" /f /v "WindowSize"       /t "REG_DWORD"  /d 0x00200040
    ) > nul

    start "%consoleName%" cmd.exe
```

The registry stores the configuration for multiple customizations of the console. This code just creates a basic customization associated to a window title and starts a new console with this title to use the indicated parameters.

For more information, the [documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc978570.aspx) includes a complete reference of the values.