# How to change cmd font size, without going through properties?

Tags: windows, command-prompt

I was wondering if there is a way to change the size of the font by using a command. 
I know you can change buffersize and windowsize but I can't seem to find a command to change the fontsize/(resolution?).

[image]

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905911/2861476) can help

Comment: thanks this fixes the problem, but lets say I have a file named test.bat and I use the method in the link provided, I need 2 seperate .bat files in order to make my project run. Is there a way to get it all in 1 .bat file?

Comment: pseudocode: `if not flag exists ( create console configuration, set flag, start my self, leave ) else do work ` and use a system environment, aditional argument, ... as flag

Comment: alright thanks ;) (you can put it up as an answer if you'd like)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt

Answer (score 6):

I came here looking for the the answer to the same question, and it seems like a good idea to finally close it with an answer for the reference of anyone else. **The answer is that, to the best of my research and knowledge, there is currently no native way to change the font size of CMD from the command line itself.** There is a very involved, [hacky solution outlined here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27127760/1191147) that works by invoking Powershell from CMD, for anyone that doesn't mind the work involved in implementing that soluition.

The lack of a native feature for this is, in my opinion, a massive failing of CMD. Being able to use commands like `color 0f` to change the background and foreground colours of a console window without providing similar functionality to change other font properties is really inconsistent UX.

Comment: `inconsistent UX`, sounds like a problem the WHOLE Windows is having