# Specify the size of command prompt when executing a batch file

Tags: batch-file

EDIT: How do I specify the font of command prompt and the size of the window? I'm using Windows 7 Professional. **OK. I'm sorry, I'm trying to use a command to do the above things, so I'm not accepting those "press-the-properties" answer.**

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905911/2861476) could help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to change the console font size programmatically, see [this page](https://4sysops.com/archives/change-powershell-console-font-size-with-cmdlet/) and [this page](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/cb72e4e6-4a68-4a2e-89b7-cc43a860349e).  You basically have to copypaste that module source from the technet page into a new file called `SetConsoleFont.psm1` on your local machine.  Put it into a folder of the same name without ext (so it becomes `SetConsoleFont\SetConsoleFont.psm1`).  From the command line, `powershell -command "echo $env:PSModulePath"` to see where you should put that `SetConsoleFont\` folder (probably in `%userprofile%\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\Modules`).

If you want to include that technet script within your batch script and have your batch script create `[module_path_dir]\SetConsoleFont\SetConsoleFont.psm1` on the user's machine, I suggest a [batch script heredoc](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15032476/1683264) would be an easy way to include it and write it dynamically.

With the module in your module path, you can now use it from the cmd line.

`powershell -command "&{set-executionpolicy remotesigned; Import-Module SetConsoleFont; Get-ConsoleFontInfo | Format-Table -AutoSize}"`

will show you a table of the font sizes available to your console.  Choose one from the `nFont` column and activate it like this:

`powershell -command "&{set-executionpolicy remotesigned; Import-Module SetConsoleFont; Set-ConsoleFont 6}"`

If all you want to do is resize the console window and buffer, that's much simpler.  No modules or importing or execution policy overriding is needed.  `mode con: cols=n1 lines=n2` will change the window dimensions, and there's a PowerShell one-liner for changing the buffer (scrollback history) size.

```
:: Resize the console window and increase the buffer to 10000 lines
call :consize 80 33 80 10000

:: put the main part of your bat script here.
:: script
:: script
:: script
:: etc.

goto :EOF

:consize <columns> <lines> <buffercolumns> <bufferlines>
:: change console window dimensions and buffer
mode con: cols=%1 lines=%2
powershell -command "&{$H=get-host;$W=$H.ui.rawui;$B=$W.buffersize;$B.width=%3;$B.height=%4;$W.buffersize=$B;}"
goto :EOF
```

Comment: Let me try this. I'll reply ASAP.

Comment: I (and other people) found that it is not working on Windows 10. The `Import` command and the `Get-ConsoleFontInfo` function return nothing. Some also get permission errors when running the `Set-ConsoleFont` function.

Comment: The SetConsoleFont module from the 4sysops.com article is now a broken link. It will redirect you to learn.microsoft.com's "Browse code samples" where you can search for SetConsoleFont but that returns nothing.

Comment: I have found a backup of this module at 
https://github.com/MikeFal/PowerShell/blob/master/SetConsoleFont/SetConsoleFont.psm1

Answer (score 0):

If you create a shortcut to cmd.exe you can rightclick on it and select "properties". Here you can set font, color, window and buffer size, etc.