# How to make the console font bigger when running a batch?

Tags: windows, file, batch-file, cmd, font-size

I have the following batch file which I use to run my Minecraft server: (run.bat)

```
@echo off
java -Xmx1G -jar mcserver.jar
```

I looked on many forums, and I'm too lazy to begin studying batch code, so I decided to ask here.
I want to insert a passage of code that will set the font size in the console to a certain size (for example, 18px). BUT: I don't want the console to run with big font on every other batch file or cmd prompt opened... only in this file. I appreciate any answers :)

- I use Windows 10.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Specify the size of command prompt when executing a batch file](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27120267/specify-the-size-of-command-prompt-when-executing-a-batch-file)

Comment: you are running this on windows ?

Comment: Sorry for not mentioning. I added it to the post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Create a shortcut to your batch file (I assume you have a batch file)
2. Go to Properties of the Shortcut
3. Look for the tab Fonts
4. Choose 8x12 or 16x12
5. Save the shortcut

Now if you run with the same shortcut it should show as per font size selected

**Here are screenshots**

[image: Create Shortcut and properties]

[image: Select Font tab and font size]