# Size batch windows and set in specific location

Tags: windows, batch-file, ping, window-resize

I have multiple batch files I run to monitor my network links.  I have one of the sets of code below.  I run a single batch file to open all the files at once.  I then have to reposition them across the top of the screen so I can open internet explorer to display solar winds across the bottom portion of the screen.  I want to add to the code I am using to set where each window will open.  Thank you in advance for the help.

```
@echo off
TITLE = VoIP Link
mode 50,20

    setlocal enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

    rem Get address from command line
    set "address=13.2.9.6"
    if not defined address set "address=127.0.0.1"

    rem Configure levels and colors 
    rem The format is initialValue:color in value descending format
    set "levels=9000:4F 178:E0 146:2F 0:E0"

    rem infinite loop
    for /l %%i in () do (
        rem retrieve information from ping command
        set "rtt=Timed Out"
        set "ttl=?"
        for /f "tokens=3,4 delims==^<" %%a in (
            'ping -n 1 "%address%" ^| find "TTL="'
        ) do for /f "tokens=1 delims=m" %%c in ("%%a") do (
            set /a "rtt=%%c"
            set "ttl=%%b"
        )

        rem retrieve color
        set "color="
        for %%z in (%levels%) do for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=:" %%a in ("%%z") do (
            if not defined color if !rtt! geq %%a set "color=%%b"
        )

        rem show information
        if defined color color !color!
        echo(!time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]

        rem save to log
        for /f "tokens=1-4 delims=.:-/ " %%a in ("!date!") do (
            >> "%%b-%%c-%%d_%%a_VOIP Link 1.txt" echo(!date! - !time! - %address% - rtt[!rtt!]
        )

        rem wait and repeat the process
        ping -n 3 localhost >nul 2>nul 
    )
```

Comment: Maybe [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24905911/2861476) could help

Comment: or this http://www.commandline.co.uk/cmdow/

Answer (score 3):

If you start each window like this

```
start "A Window Title" cmd /k <optional command>
```

Goto the Window's properties. Set size and colour, untick *Let Windows Position*.

When you start it the same way in the future it will remember it's size and color.

Answer (score 0):

There is no batch file command to do that. Nor is there any scripting (or .NET) command to do anything to a window that isn't the code's (or started by it). Programs shouldn't mess with others'.

I have a handfull of VB6 very basic programs to resize, move, ontop, and change titlebar (with source code - each is 6 lines or so) at https://skydrive.live.com/redir?resid=E2F0CE17A268A4FA!121

Only API calls can do this so you need a real programming language. It is against the philosophy to do this.

Now CMD remembers it's windows position based on titlebar. Make shortcuts that take advantage of that, see `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Console`

I suggest you look at the CMD title thing.

Hers a VB6 prog to move a window.

```
Public Declare Function FindWindow Lib "user32" Alias "FindWindowA" (ByVal lpClassName As String, ByVal lpWindowName As String) As Long
Public Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Long, ByVal x As Long, ByVal y As Long, ByVal cx As Long, ByVal cy As Long, ByVal wFlags As Long) As Long
Public Const SWP_DRAWFRAME = &H20
Public Const SWP_FRAMECHANGED = &H20        '  The frame changed: send WM_NCCALCSIZE
Public Const SWP_HIDEWINDOW = &H80
Public Const SWP_NOACTIVATE = &H10
Public Const SWP_NOCOPYBITS = &H100
Public Const SWP_NOMOVE = &H2
Public Const SWP_NOOWNERZORDER = &H200      '  Don't do owner Z ordering
Public Const SWP_NOREDRAW = &H8
Public Const SWP_NOREPOSITION = &H200
Public Const SWP_NOSIZE = &H1
Public Const SWP_NOZORDER = &H4
Public Const SWP_SHOWWINDOW = &H40

Public Declare Function SetWindowText Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowTextA" (ByVal hwnd As Long, ByVal lpString As String) As Long

Sub Main()
On Error Resume Next
HWND_TOPMOST = -1

CmdLine = Command()

A = Split(CmdLine, Chr(32), 2, 1)
B = Split(A(0), "x", 2, 1)

hwindows = FindWindow(vbNullString, A(1))
Ret = SetWindowPos(hwindows, HWND_NOTOPMOST, B(0), B(1), 0, 0, SWP_NOREPOSITION + SWP_NOSIZE)
If Ret = 0 Then MsgBox "Set Pos Error is " & Err.LastDllError
End Sub
```

Comment: @carpetsmoker so how do I make the file remember it's preious location?  I cannot access your skydrive link from work

Comment: I do not have vb6.  We are running a stock windows 7 enterprise image that is locked down.

Comment: You have VB.NET then, it's installed all computers. See this on how to translate using notepad/vb.net compiler. https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/df0248cb-612f-4e2f-9665-11c68c401458/how-to-call-win32-api-calls-in-vbscript-and-jscript-sample-windows-api-functions?forum=scripting

Answer (score 0):

To size batch windows and set in specific location, once the command prompt window opens, right click in the title bar, select properties, go to the layout tab, uncheck "Let system position window", and then select Window Size and Window Position according to what you want. You can select other attributes as well (font, font size, colors, etc.) from the other tabs in Properties. It will open in that set format from then on.