# Change Font Size on Node JS Command Prompt on Windows

Tags: node.js, windows, command-line, fonts

I'm trying to change the font size on the NodeJS command prompt. With the standard Windows Command Window, you can use the following steps to change the font size:

1. Right Click 'Command Prompt'
2. Choose 'Properties'
3. Click on the 'Font' tab
4. Adjust the font
5. Click Apply / OK

If you do the same with the Node JS command prompt, none of your changes are applied. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: I guess there are a few modules to change the color but my point is if you want to use console then you can settle for command prompt as well.

Comment: the steps you talk about are for changing the application settings for the terminal emulator itself. If you want to change those settings from inside the application, [that's not a trivial, or cross-platform thing](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/945527/modify-cmd-exe-properties-using-the-command-prompt).

Comment: It works the same way with the Node JS command prompt. The changes to the font size persist on my Windows computer, so perhaps you ahve a different issue? You can also click on the title bar in the node.js window to get to the Properties.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

As with many things in life, it's a permissions problem.  I ran into the same issue and resolved it as follows:

1. Right click the "Node.js command prompt" shortcut.
2. Go to the Security tab
3. Click "Edit..."
4. (optional) Note your current permissions if you want to revert this later.
5. Select your username and give yourself full permissions on the file.
6. Click OK
7. Go to the Font tab.
8. Change font to your desired settings.
9. Click OK.
10. (optional) Follow steps 1-6 again, this time changing back your permissions to their original settings.

You could also make your own copy of the shortcut somewhere else, which would also bypass the permissions issue.