# Changing the font of console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, console

I have developed a console application with Java. Now I am distributing it to the users who do not have administrator privileges. Users will run the program in Windows 7 or later. They will start the program by double clicking to a .bat file. I need that bat file, because I have to add some variables to the path before the program starts. In addition, I need to show some Turkish characters (such as ğ, ü) in console. Therefore, I  change encoding to the 65001 or 857. However, the console's default font is set to "raster font" that cannot show Turkish characters. So, I wonder if there is a programmatic way of changing the font or not in bat file or not.

Actually, I have encountered a solution in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/33548731/2979477, but I am looking for another way that do not use a .lnk shortcut, because I do not want users to suppose that it is a shortcut and can be deleted. So, I am open to any kind of solutions.

By the way this is the bat file:

```
@echo off
set %PATH%;C:\Users\some_path;
chcp 857
title My Program
color 0A
mode con: cols=100 lines=45
REM run my java program
```

Comment: might better fit to https://superuser.com/ ...

Comment: Your second line does not do what you said you needed a batch file for.

Comment: @Compo Actually, I have tested it and it works. I will check it again.

Comment: @Mofi The font size is not that important. The only thing that I want to have a font which supports Turkish characters.

Comment: Your test result is mistaken; what it should say is `Set "PATH=C:\Users\some_path;%PATH%"`. Note that I switched the order for safety because you have no idea if the existing path includes a closing semi-colon.